# PHPExcel Csv reader set encoding

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I have this so far, but when I read from my csv I get an empty value because it is a non utf-8 encoded csv file.

```
public function process_woe() 
{
 $objPHPExcel   = new PHPExcel();
 $woe_processed = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex( 0 );
 $objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( $this->woe_filepath );
 $woe           = $objReader->getActiveSheet();
 $rcount        = 1;
 $rncount       = 1;

}
```

This string returns an empty string when I try to write it on a utf-8 encoding:

```
"Caruso�s Prostate EZE MAX health indications:
� Management of symptoms Medically Diagnosed Prostate Enlargement
� Prostate gland health                                                                                  
� Antioxidant for the prostate gland"
```

When I try to use `setInputEncoding()` I get an error, for example:

```
$objReader->setInputEncoding('ISO');
$woe->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-7');
$woe->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-1'); 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::setInputEncoding() –
```

Comment: It has a `setInputEncoding` method, did you try that?

Comment: $objReader->setInputEncoding('ISO'); already tried this one i get an error

Comment: 1. I doubt that `ISO` on its own is considered a valid character encoding anywhere, and 2. saying that you _get_ an error without mentioning what that error actually _says_, is anything but helpful.

Comment: $woe->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-7');
  $woe->setInputEncoding('ISO-8859-1');

Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::setInputEncoding()

Comment: Please provide a link to what exact library you are using there, “phpexcel” is ambiguous.

Comment: http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel

Comment: `setInputEncoding` is a method of the `PHPExcel_Reader_*` classes, you need to call it on the reader instance, not on a sheet. Not sure if that will work with current code though, because presumably this needs to be set _before_ the data is read, but you are creating your reader instance with `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load`, so that probably needs to be rewritten. But before you start with that, it might make sense to pay some attention to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel#phpexcel---dead first maybe …

Comment: Is this an old project you're working on? First thing you notice when looking at the library's website is the big "Stop using it!" text. Maybe you should look into a different library?